# Пропала возможность изменения TabBarController

Tags: xcode

Всем привет !

Раньше мог добавить в `TabBar Controller` снизу `item`, теперь я не могу даже изменить то, что есть. Не могу понять в чем причина.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S.** *если надо будет к вопросу добавить (скриншот итд.) пожалуйста, напишите в комментарии.*

Comment: а как вы добавляете?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko если Вы имеете ввиду TabBar как добавляю, то просто перетаскиваю из  "Object library". Проблема в том, что я наверное что то перемудрил с Global Tint. Раньше когда я кликал на какой нибудь item внизу Tab Bar, то можно было изменять эти кнопки. Сейчас нельзя =(